# Is it possible to do Batch Transform from files stored on an other server than Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, classification, amazon-sagemaker

I have prepared a CNN and would like to deploy it on AWS to do some image classification. However, the images are stored on an other server than Amazon S3.

Do I have to load all the images on S3 prior to calling the endpoint to make inference ? Do AWS handle like a "cache memory" so I can get images from that server without bringing them on S3 ?

On an other note, is there any alternative way to make classification of large amount of images ? The output should be a Json file. I'm quite lost with all the AWS features.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Batch Transform is limited to S3 as an input source.
To better suggest an Inference method can you please state the size of the input data and latency requirements?
SageMaker also offers Asynchronous Inference that allows you to point to an S3 path(input) and select an Instances and count with an optional scaling policy to scale down to zero to save costs. The maximum size of input for Async is 1GB.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about using Postman to send the links of my photos so I could upload these photos on a S3 bucket and then call the endpoint to do inference. There is no real latency requirements (I don't need instant feedback) and I would need to classify around 50k photos of size 0.5Mb approximately. I'm quite concerned about downloading ~25Gb of photos.